# Does my company own my script?

Tags: python, licensing

I wrote a python script to handle data and create a usable form for a application.  A large bank overseas has requested my script.  So I bundled it to a exe and attached a Apache license to it. I was called into the office and told to remove my name from the script and remove the Apache license?  Does this sound fair? Does my company own my script, my job title is not a programmer for the company if that matters?

Comment: If you wrote it during your work hours, and the initial need for it was for the company, i think it owns it, but it may edpends on your country laws.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about people and/or HR and/or legal issues rather than programming ones.  It might be more appropriate for [programmers.se].

Comment: It sounds a bit that you have invented something because of your work you normally do. This might be owned by the company you work for, but they probably need also to pay you extra. Check that with a lawyer she should be able to help you. This makes more sense, especially as you're not fluent in that situation and you're perhaps not in a position feeling well to negotiate with your employee. You lawyer can then handle that too.

Comment: Having your name with that script sounds like it is your personal right to have that there, regardless what your company *asks* for. But that might also depend on local law, a good lawyer would check each individual point of that in accordance to local laws, like copyright, personal rights, workers rights, inventors rights etc.. When you visit your lawyer, keep a copy of the contract and the work you created with you as well a copy of the written statements you have from your office.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule of thumb is that if it was created on company time, the company has paid for it, and thus owns it. However, defining what "company time" is, depends on many a factor.

In addition, checkout this http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/19422/if-im-working-at-a-company-do-they-have-intellectual-property-rights-to-the-st -- you'll find some pretty good arguments, but it is mostly focused on software developers. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

All labor relations are governed by the contract. A copy of the contract should be you. So, see your contract.

Answer (score 0):

Check what your contract states. Most companies have you sign legal documents where it states what is company property. If you wrote that script at work then yes most likely than not it will be company property since you are on company time and you are using company resources. Your best option is to read over your contract and see if it states anything about intellectual property. There might be a good amount of lawyer jargon but it should be fairly clear.